# Add icon at specific row in table Angular

Tags: html, angular, types, html-table

I want to add an icon beside row #1, No.1 as shown in the table below.

[image]

```
<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
 <button mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Tooltip"><mat-icon>Test</mat-icon><button></ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
```

```
<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td></ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
</tr><tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

How could I solve this? How to insert the icon only at one row?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add your icon between `<th>...</th>` tag like the example below, hope this helps!

```
<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
  {{element.position}} 
  
  <!-- Add Here -->
  <button mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Tooltip"><mat- 
  icon>Test</mat-icon><button>

</td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
```